# Can I use JAVAC to compile a project with multiple files and directories?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, javac

I'm working on a very large project that has associated class files in multiple directories, all stemming from the root dir \src.

I'm trying to compile a file in src\solution\ (called Console.java) that uses imports from other directories in the src, which are still uncompiled.

So if I want to compile Console.java outside of an IDE, how do I go about doing that? Oh yeah, I also have some external JARs which need to be included in the build.

Thanks! I appreciate it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [javac option to compile all java files under a given directory recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-all-java-files-under-a-given-directory-recursively)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look at using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to create a build script.  It's a little bit of work now but it'll pay off over the lifetime of your project.

Answer (score 2):

javac comes with two options, that might help you her:

```
-c path/to/one/jar;path/to/another/jar
```

for libraries and

```
-s path/to/src/solution/java;path/to/src/test/java
```

for sourcefiles. It's worth a try.

Comment: But this way (-s); I have to give all the folder names which contains java files rit ..? If i give root dir; Doesn't wont go search (.java) in sub directories for dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear on your specific requirements, but what your asking is almost certainly possible.  You might want to take a look at the javac options, and see what you can find that will help you.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options

For example, for the external .jars you need, those need to be included in your classpath using the -classpath option.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want a build tool. You might want to look at these questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80622/maven-or-ant
- [What do you use for a complex build process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521117/what-do-you-use-for-a-complex-build-process)
- [What are some good java make utilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169293/what-are-some-good-java-make-utilities)