# javac option to compile all java files under a given directory recursively

Tags: java, javac

I am using the javac compiler to compile java files in my project. The files are distributed over several packages like this: `com.vistas.util`, `com.vistas.converter`, `com.vistas.LineHelper`, `com.current.mdcontect`.

Each of these packages has several java files. I am using javac like this:

```
javac com/vistas/util/*.java com/vistas/converter/*.java
      com.vistas.LineHelper/*.java com/current/mdcontect/*.java
```

(in one line)

Instead of giving so many paths, how can I ask the compiler to compile recursively all the java files from the parent com directory?

Comment: You should really have a look at tools such as Ant or Maven.

Comment: This SO post might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864630/can-i-use-javac-to-compile-a-project-with-multiple-files-and-directories

Comment: If your project is modular, this is a nice solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72658417/2147927

Answer (score 263, accepted):

I would also suggest using some kind of build tool ([Ant](http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheAnt/article.html) or [Maven](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2005/jw-1205-maven.html), Ant is already suggested and is easier to start with) or an IDE that handles the compilation (Eclipse uses incremental compilation with reconciling strategy, and you don't even have to care to press any *"Compile"* buttons).

### Using Javac

If you need to try something out for a larger project and don't have any proper build tools nearby, you can always use a small trick that `javac` offers: the classnames to compile can be specified in a file. You simply have to pass the name of the file to `javac` with the `@` prefix.

If you can create a list of all the `*.java` files in your project, it's easy:

```
# Linux / MacOS
$ find -name "*.java" > sources.txt
$ javac @sources.txt

:: Windows
> dir /s /B *.java > sources.txt
> javac @sources.txt
```

- **The advantage** is that is is a quick and easy solution.
- **The drawback** is that you have to regenerate the `sources.txt` file each time you create a new source or rename an existing one file which is an easy to forget (thus error-prone) and tiresome task.

### Using a build tool

On the long run it is better to use a tool that was designed to build software.

#### Using Ant

If you create a simple `build.xml` file that describes how to build the software:

```
<project default="compile">
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

you can compile the whole software by running the following command:

```
$ ant
```

- **The advantage** is that you are using a standard build tool that is easy to extend.
- **The drawback** is that you have to download, set up and learn an additional tool. Note that most of the IDEs (like NetBeans and Eclipse) offer great support for writing build files so you don't have to download anything in this case.

#### Using Maven

Maven is not that trivial to set up and work with, but learning it pays well. Here's a great tutorial to [start a project within 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).

- **It's main advantage** (for me) is that it handles dependencies too, so you won't need to download any more Jar files and manage them by hand and I found it more useful for building, packaging and testing larger projects.
- **The drawback** is that it has a steep learning curve, and if Maven plugins like to suppress errors :-) Another thing is that quite a lot of tools also operate with Maven repositories (like [Sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) for Scala, [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) for Ant, [Graddle](http://www.gradle.org/) for Groovy).

### Using an IDE

Now that what could boost your development productivity. There are a few open source alternatives (like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/), I prefer the former) and even commercial ones (like [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)) which are quite popular and powerful.

They can manage the project building in the background so you don't have to deal with all the command line stuff. However, it always comes handy if you know what *actually happens* in the background so you can hunt down occasional errors like a `ClassNotFoundException`.

### One additional note

For larger projects, it is always advised to use an IDE **and** a build tool. The former boosts your productivity, while the latter makes it possible to use different IDEs with the project (e.g., Maven can generate Eclipse project descriptors with a simple `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command). Moreover, having a project that can be tested/built with a single line command is easy to introduce to new colleagues and into a continuous integration server for example. Piece of cake :-)

Comment: When using `javac`, it would be better to specify an output directory. `find -name "*.java" > sources.txt && javac -d bin @sources.txt`. Otherwise *.class files are saved to the directory where sources are.

Comment: Absolutely true. Although in my opinion, if someone has just started to play around with `javac`, the concept of `CLASSPATH`, how to run code with `java`, how to deal with packages, which should be the root folder for running, etc. are usually not clear. Thus I omitted the output dir. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: For mac users coming across this, the `find` command is: `find . -name "*.java" > sources.txt` (note the `.`)

Comment: @MrDuk What does adding the "." do? Is it for searching within the current directory?

Comment: @BradySheehan it will start to search from the given path. "." means start from the current dictionary. Note that you **have** to specify a path for find (in OS X)

Comment: The approach using "javac @sources.txt" won't work if a file path has spaces

Comment: in windows you can do it in one command: for/F %g IN ('dir *.java /b /s') DO javac %g this way you will not need to regenerate a file in the system

Comment: Guys just pls think before you change the code. Sometimes it becomes far more like a mess when you change it without the context (i.e., for me it's fine if you rename sources.txt to src.txt IF you go throught the text and do the updates there too).

Comment: Is there any way to use the results of find but not have to write them to a file?

Comment: In windows, how to exclude the .java.bak files? They will cause problems, in the case of "dir /s /B *.java". And also it contains the folders which also will fail the javac

Comment: If your file path has spaces you will see invalid flag error on compile, so to avoid this error enclose the path in string and escape the backslash some thing like this -- "c://Java class//Test.java"

Answer (score 45):

```
find . -name "*.java" -print | xargs javac
```

Kinda brutal, but works like hell. (Use only on small programs, it's absolutely not efficient)

Comment: If you use this consider `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0 ...` instead to not break on spaces in filenames

Answer (score 43):

In the usual case where you want to compile your whole project you can simply supply javac with your main class and let it compile all required dependencies:

`javac -sourcepath . path/to/Main.java`

Comment: Very simple method, does not rely on extra files

Comment: This is the best and the simplest one for people who don't have much time to learn Ant (like me)

Comment: It's lazy unfortunately. If you don't touch `Main.java`, which you probably wouldn't just after creating your second file, nothing else gets compiler.

Comment: Doesn't work well here either. Some dependencies are not recompiled despite being changed. @TomHawtin-tackline I tried touch before on the main but nothing. Maybe touch on all is required. Kind of awkward though.

Answer (score 33):

If your shell supports it, would something like this work ?

```
javac com/**/*.java
```

If your shell does not support `**`, then maybe

```
javac com/*/*/*.java
```

works (for all packages with 3 components - adapt for more or less).

Comment: I have attempted to use this in command prompt on windows 10. Can someone confirm if it works on windows 10 or if I am doing it wrong please

Answer (score 9):

`javac -cp "jar_path/*" $(find . -name '*.java')`

(I prefer not to use xargs because it can split them up and run javac multiple times, each with a subset of java files, some of which may import other ones not specified on the same javac command line)

If you have an App.java entrypoint, freaker's way with -sourcepath is best. It compiles every other java file it needs, following the import-dependencies. eg:

`javac -cp "jar_path/*" -sourcepath src/ src/com/companyname/modulename/App.java`

You can also specify a target class-file dir: `-d target/`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just using make with a simple makefile that looks like this:

```
JAVAC = javac -Xlint:unchecked
sources = $(shell find . -type f -name '*.java')
classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

all : $(classes)

clean :
        rm -f $(classes)

%.class : %.java
        $(JAVAC) $<
```

It compiles the sources one at a time and only recompiles if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I would advice you to learn using [ant](http://ant.apache.org), which is very-well suited for this task and is very easy to grasp and well documented.

You would just have to define a target like this in the build.xml file:

```
<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="your/source/directory"
           destdir="your/output/directory"
           classpath="xyz.jar" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

javac command does not follow a recursive compilation process, so you have either specify each directory when running command, or provide a text file with directories you want to include:

```
javac -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" @java_sources.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

this one is pretty cool:
I am located at the project root.

```
find . -name *.java -exec javac {} -d ../out \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this in an Xcode JNI project to recursively build my test classes:

```
find ${PROJECT_DIR} -name "*.java" -print | xargs javac -g -classpath ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} -d ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use Maven (or the likes) in all my projects. But once needing a compilation with only `javac` I came across with the following Windows BAT script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rmdir /s /q target
rmdir /s /q generated
mkdir target
mkdir generated

set JAVA_FILES=

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /s /b src\*.java') do (
    set "JAVA_FILES=!JAVA_FILES! "%%i""
)

javac -d target -encoding UTF-8 -classpath src; -sourcepath src; -s generated %JAVA_FILES%

endlocal
```

Most likely it needs some customization in the details. The drawback is that it doesn't do incremental compilation and recompiles everything each time, but this is what I need for now.