# automatically compiling multiple java packages

Tags: java, class, compilation, package

I'm trying to compile a Java project from the command line. The project contains class files in different packages. The program compiles and run fine if I specify every java file of every package. Here's my directory structure:

```
toplevel/
    mainFile.java
    level1/ (Contains fileA.java)
```

Now if I do `javac -classpath ./toplevel toplevel/mainFile.java toplevel/level1/fileA.java`, this compiles fine and I can run it with `java toplevel/mainFile`.
Now if a create a new folder called 'level2' in level1 and create a class 'B' inside it, the new directory structure becomes:

```
toplevel/
    mainFile.java
    level1/ (Contains fileA.java)
        level2/ (Contains fileB.java)
```

To compile this I have to do:
`javac -classpath ./toplevel toplevel/mainFile.java toplevel/level1/fileA.java toplevel/level1/level2/fileB.java` which is becoming ridiculous. Is there an instruction that recursively compiles each package and the files inside it?

Comment: Why not use a build tool like ant or maven? It will be trivial with those.

Comment: Possible repeat of [javac option to compile recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-recursively)

Comment: @rocketboy I don't want to use any build tool this requires learning some extra stuff. The user has to be able to run it from the command line

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `-sourcepath` flag. From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#sourcepath),

> -sourcepath sourcepath
>   Specify the source code path to search for class or interface definitions. As with the user class path, source path entries are separated by semicolons (;) and can be directories, JAR archives, or ZIP archives. If packages are used, the local path name within the directory or archive must reflect the package name.