# Compiling Java files in sub-directories

Tags: java, compilation

I would like to be able to compile all java files in all subdirectories from what I'm working in.

I know how to compile all java files in the same directory, but how do I do it for all subdirectories (and subdirectories of those, etc.)?

Comment: Which IDE or build tool are you using?  I wouldn't suggest you use the command line unless you like doing things the hardest way possible. (In which case you are not alone)

Comment: I am using the command line.

Comment: I use maven and an IntelliJ.  When I want to run a program, I don't need to think about which files/directories need to be re-compiled, I just press `Run` to run or `Debug` to debug.

Comment: Instead of writing individual solutions, I'd provide you the link to another **stackoverflow** post that answers it well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

**Using Javac**

You have to know all the directories beforehand, or be able to use wildcard.
The command goes this way:

```
javac dir1/*.java dir2/*.java dir3/dir4/*.java dir3/dir5/*.java dir6/*src/*.java
```

**(OR)**

If you can create a list of all the *.java files in your project, it's easy:

Linux

```
$ find -name "*.java" > sources.txt
$ javac @sources.txt
```

Windows

```
> dir /s /B *.java > sources.txt
> javac @sources.txt
```

**Using a build tool**

It is always better to use a tool that was designed to build software.

**Using Ant**

If you create a simple build.xml file that describes how to build the software:

```
<project default="compile">
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

you can compile the whole software by running the following command:

$ ant

Now that you know all the ways (at least, most ways), the choice is yours! :-)

Comment: Thanks! So would `javac */.java` work? That would only work for one directory level though.

Comment: edited the answer with more information. If the answer helped, please upvote, and "accept as answer". It helps newbies like me @stackoverflow :-)

Comment: For multiple directories, I would suggest you use the ant script. However, if you want to keep things simple, you can use the "find" or "dir" option (i've mentioned those in my answer). That works for all subdirectories!

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm trying to run this all from a C++ file using `system()` calls. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

try using ant script, give the base dir of source file to srcdir

```
<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>
```