# Build Eclipse project automatically in a batch process

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, build

My project needs periodic source downloading from a shared drive. That is in the form of a zip file. After extracting them, I need to checkout some sources from SVN as well. But time shouldn't be spent during office hours for that. Hence a bat file is created which does all these including zip downloading, extraction, SVN checkout, compilation and opening eclipse.

In the process of compilation, I get the following error

*unable to access jarfile /plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0*

But this is bypassed and eclipse is opened without the option "Build Automatically" checked. Because of this the workspace doesn't get compiled and hence need to spend sometime for building the workspace.

Any idea to set the Build Automatically true without manual intervention?
Otherwise it would be appreciated if the source files could be compiled without the above said error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not use Eclipse to build your project in a batch process. First, you run in the type of problem you are describing, but you also have the problem of the additional overhead of running eclipse, and this make your build system very platform-dependent.

A cleaner solution would be to call `javac` from your batch process. See the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html). Also a useful post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-all-java-files-under-a-given-directory-recursively).

An even better solution would be to implement your build script in [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), instead of batch. Ant is supported by Eclipse, but can be run independently on any platform. It supports doing everything you describe in your build process:

- Downloading: [Get task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html)
- Extracting: [Unzip task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html)
- SVN checkout: [SVNAnt](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html)
- Compiling: [Javac task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)
- Jar: [Jar task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)
- etc...