# What's the equivalent of this console line commands for javac in Windows?

Tags: java, linux, windows, ubuntu, javac

```
javac `find $(sourcefoulder) -name "*.java"` (on a make file)
```

or

```
javac $(find sourcefolder -name "*.java") (on the terminal)
```

I have windows setup with PATH variables, both javac and java working.

Thanks

Comment: One well-known cross-platform equivalent is [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), or similar Java-aware build tool. It is ok for one build tool to invoke another when mixing languages.

Comment: lot of answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-all-java-files-under-a-given-directory-recursively