# compiling entire java package and classes via ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, compilation, package

so, I've written 3 simple classes in 3 different class files: 
Point.java, Rectangle.java, Circle.java,

and a main class named main.java.
they are all in the same folder name shapes.

the main class just have a main function that declare each of these shapes and print them.

all the files are in this path:
~/Downloads/myProject/src/shapes/

can someone please help me with the specific command i should write to compile this main class?

note that when i use this command:
   javac -cp src/shapes src/shapes/main.java
the compiler returns errors like this:

src/shape/main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Point p1 = new Point(1.5, 2);
        ^
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class main

for each shape i declared...

Comment: Do you have a package declaration in the classes? Or are they all in the default package?

Comment: It may help if you add the source code to reproduce your problem -- head [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section of the help pages

Answer (score 0):

```
javac Point.java
javac Rectangle.java
javac Circle.java
javac main.java
```

Simply compile them in the correct order: Point is used in Rectangle and Circle (I imagine), so compile it *before* the others.

Remember that in Java class name should always be title case (AKA: Main.java, not main.java).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, but in which order? You don't know.

Comment: Doesn't matter which order.

Comment: @LorenzoBarbagli but javac can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

[javac option to compile all java files under a given directory recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-all-java-files-under-a-given-directory-recursively)