# javac does not compile files in subfolder

Tags: java, compilation

I have a folder containing some java files plus a subfolder with further files. Something like this:

```
C:\MyFolder
       file1.java
       file2.java
       ...
       \subfolder
             file3.java
             file4.java
             ...
```

My main file is `file1.java`, which calls all the other files. From the terminal, if I type `javac MyFolder/file1.java` I get the files in `MyFolder` compiled. However, even though `file1.java` calls `file3.java` and `file4.java`, these ones are not compiled. How can I make them compiled together with the rest? 
Actually, I should say that they got compiled on the first instance. But now they don't anymore. If I change something to `file3` or `file4` and I compile `file1` again, when I run `file1` this keeps running with the previously compiled versions of `file3` and `file4`.

Comment: You are a beginner. Everything you can think of asking at this point ... has for sure been asked here. Many times. And answered. Please do some prior research before putting up questions here!

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-all-java-files-under-a-given-directory-recursively