# Package missing in basic package structure in Java

Tags: java, import, package

I have a basic package structure. I have Main class and Player class in first package 'pack1' and then in subdirectory 'pack2' I have a Monster class. I need to use javac and java commands when running this program because it's my homework, but it just tells me that package pack1.pack2 does not exist. I am trying to run it by using command 'javac Main.java'. If I remove packages and place them in the same folder, then the command 'javac Main.java' works fine. When I run this program by using Visual Studio Code "Run" command it runs fine.

My file structure looks like this:

```
pack1
|_ Main.java
|_ Player.java
|_ pack2
   |_ Monster.java
```

I have been fighting with this for the past 2 hours now, trying to google different solutions but with no luck. I am probably using the javac command in a wrong way. I have tried using -d argument and some path arguments, but since I don't understand them clearly it probably was not the correct way of using them.

```java
package pack1;
import pack1.pack2.Monster;

public class Main extends Monster {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        killPlayer();
    }
}
```

```java
package pack1;

public class Player {

    public void shout() {
        System.out.println("Shout");
    }
}
```

```java
package pack1.pack2;
import pack1.Player;

public abstract class Monster {

    public static void killPlayer() {
        Player p = new Player();
        p.shout();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explicitly give all file paths to the javac compiler. Take a look at this post to recursively compile all files in a dir.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769536/3450689

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on pack1 parent folder:

Compile all your java files.

```
javac $(find . -name "*.java")
```

And then,

```
java pack1.Main
```