# How to create .jar from the command line with a huge number of .class files?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, compilation, javac

So I have inherited a project with `org/projectname/Client.class` containing the main class, and tons of other .class files in directories like `org/projectname/` and `org/projectname/backend/` (and some libraries in `lib/`, but I assume those are already compiled into the .class files and can be ignored).

I want to make a .jar executable that when run like `java -jar Client.jar`, starts off with `Client.java` and has all the classes/libraries inside that it needs to run, from the *command line*.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javac option to compile all java files under a given directory recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-all-java-files-under-a-given-directory-recursively)

Comment: why not use maven or ant or gradle?

Comment: You seem to be confused as to the nature of a jar file; it is ***literally*** a regular zip file with some structure specified by Sun (now Oracle). [Using JAR Files: The Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) is a good place to start, but using maven, ant, gradle or sbt (there's always *one* more tool) is a better approach.