# How to compile with `javac` modules with `exports... to` directives without any warnings?

Tags: java, javac, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I've got three modules - a main one and two dependencies. All the modules are in the same folder level and are organised in folders `./main`, `./first` and `./second`, correspondingly.

The *second* module has only one class:

```
package characterz;

public class Freaker {

    public void freakOut() {
        System.err.println("ARGH!!!#$%@");
    }
}
```

... and its' `module-info.java` file is:

```
module second {
    exports characterz;
}
```

The *first* module has only one class:

```
package characters;

public class Captain {

    public void payRespects() {
        System.out.println("Presses \"F\" ...");
    }

}
```

... and its' `module-info.java` file is:

```
module first {
    exports characters;
    requires transitive second;
}
```

The *main* module has only one class:

```
package app;

import characters.Captain;
import characterz.Freaker;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... argz) {
        Captain cap = new Captain();
        Freaker freak = new Freaker();
        cap.payRespects();
        freak.freakOut();
    }
}
```

... and its' `module-info.java` file is:

```
module main {
    requires first;
}
```

In order to compile these three modules, I perform the following sequence of commands:

`javac -d modules/second $(find second -name *.java)`

`javac -p modules/second -d modules/first $(find first -name *.java)`

`javac -p modules/second:modules/first -d modules/main main/app/Main.java main/module-info.java`

... and it compiles fine. To make sure everything is OK we may run our program this way:
`java -p modules -m main/app.Main`

But if I try to use `exports... to` directive in the *first* module:

```
module first {
    exports characters to main;
    requires transitive second;
}
```

... then compilation process starts giving me a warning at compilation of the *first* module with this message:

```
first/module-info.java:2: warning: [module] module not found: main
    exports characters to main;
                          ^
1 warning
```

It still compiles, though. Nevertheless, how one may avoid getting these warnings when compiling modules with `exports... to` directives?

Comment: Did you try putting the main module on the module path when compiling first?

Comment: @Thomas of course, I tried putting the non-existing-yet module *main* on a `--module-path` while compiling module *first*, but it did not change anything. Even if you set `javac` param as `-p modules/second:modules/main` it wouldn't mean that `module/main` folder actually has *main* module in it. And you cannot compile *main* module without *first* and *second* both being compiled previously.

Comment: Did you try to put the main module source code into the module path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have organized your project like this:

```
.           // current working directoy
|-- src     // source code
|  |-- first
|  |-- second
|  |-- main
|-- modules // compiled stuff
   |-- first
   |-- second
   |-- main
```

Then you can compile all modules with

```
javac -d modules --module first,second,main --module-source-path src
```

from the current working directory.
No need to jump through several hoops there.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the warning about exporting `to` an unknown module by adding the `-module` compiler args.

Under Gradle (Kotlin) this would be something like:

```kotlin
    tasks.compileJava.options.compilerArgs.add("-module")
```