# How to build a jar for a project with no build.xml or pom.xml

Tags: java, build

I'd like to build a github project from source (https://github.com/rbheemana/Cobol-to-Hive/tree/master).

There seems to be no pom.xml or build.xml anywhere, just a bunch of .java files. Is it possible to build? As a result I need a jar file (like this one https://github.com/rbheemana/Cobol-to-Hive/blob/gh-pages/target/CobolSerde.jar)

Comment: Why not write a short pom.xml, copy the source code into src/main/java and compile it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a documentation to build a Jar from your Eclipse project .

https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm

Comment: But I don't have an eclipse project? There are only java files. Or do I?

Comment: You can copy your Java files into src folder of eclipse and then can create a jar.

Answer (score 0):

Suns documentation covers that, before maven & co it was done in this way:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: But what are the correct steps? Creating a jar archive is a final step, when everything is already compiled. What do I have to do first? Complie all java files one by one with javac? What about resolving dependencies?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864630/can-i-use-javac-to-compile-a-project-with-multiple-files-and-directories